# Fade in after inactive mode

Tags: gnome, brightness

Using *Brightness & Lock* I can set the time when the computer will go to inactive mode:

> Turn screen off when inactive for [1 minute].

[image]

After the time set, the screen **fades out** and then it **becomes black**, completely.

When I move the mouse or I press a key it **turns on**, again.

Is there any possible way to **fade in** the screen when it turns on from inactivity mode?

Comment: I don't believe there is a "fade in" effect included.

Comment: @TheLordofTime, Sure, this isn't included. Is there any application that does that?

Comment: I know of no application that can do that to provide that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "fade in" effect for login in Unity/Compiz yet, as KDE does, but you can promote the idea to implement it in next milestones. Is posted here for long time:

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/28471/

Hope that this helped you.

Comment: Isn't possible to build a simple application that does this? Also, not only for login but for returning from inactive mode, also.

Comment: I didn't find anything, sorry, only that brainstorm.

Answer (score 3):

There are no applications that do that or anything like what you want.

Of course it is a matter of developing a software that does that. If you have the time and expertise to do that go to [Launchpad Blueprints](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/), there you will be able to receive help from other developers. You will need to know what you are doing ; they won't do the work for you.

But if you don't have time and expertise you can use Ubuntu Brainstorm, as Leopoldo already pointed out. This idea already exists there: [Ubuntu login fade-in](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/28471/).

Also you can file a bug at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu) requesting the feature and it will be marked as *Wishlist*, and depending how many users mark the bug as affecting them, the feature might end up being released by the Ubuntu team.